# How to set selected value from the database into a dropdownlist / selectbox in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, drop-down-menu

I am using laravel 5.2 and javascript. I have an update form which contain a dropdownlist which I call using ajax with function `getTugasDetailUpdate` . My problem is how can I set the value from the database and make the dropdownlist `selected` the value from the database that I have chosen before? This below is my code in the controller.

```
public function getTugasDetailUpdate(Request $request)
{   
    $update_tugas_id = $request->get("V_ID_PK");
    $getDataListPengikut = DB::select("EXEC dbo.GET_KEMENPAR_LIST_PENGIKUT '".$update_tugas_id."'");
    $getPengikut2 = DB::select("EXEC dbo.LOV_M_PENGIKUT");
    $msg["opt"] ="";
    $no=1;
    foreach($getDataListPengikut as $dtListPengikut):

        $msg["opt"] .= '<tr>
            <td><select class="form-control" id="name_'.$dtListPengikut->KODE.'" name="nameupdate[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
                <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>'; 
                    foreach ($getPengikut2 as $getPeng){
                      $msg["opt"] .=   '<option value="'.$getPeng->KODE.'">'. $getPeng->DESKRIPSI .'</option>'; 
                    } 
                $msg["opt"] .='</select>
            </td>';
        $msg["opt"] .=  '</tr>';
    $no++;
    endforeach;
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

And how can I get a value from those controller and set it in my javascript? I want to make `var optionS = $('#name_3').html();` has an id same like `id="name_'.$dtListPengikut->KODE.'"` ? those `#name_3` is a hardcode, it could be `name_4`, `name_2`, etc.

```
var i=1;
function addMe(e){
var optionS = $('#name_3').html(); 
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field_update').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><select class="form-control" id="name_3" name="nameupdate[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">'+optionS+' </select></td></tr>'); 
}
```

Comment: Ive posted a solution and it might take you some time to implement, but it is better on a long run

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your `HTML` from your `application logic`. I suggest you use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) package, here is a minimal example:

```
@foreach($getDataListPengikut as $dtListPengikut) {
    Form::select('XXXXXXXX_name',                 //Unique name for select
          ['key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2'], //Options for this select
          null,                                   //Default option (selected)
          [
             'placeholder' => 'Pick something',   //Classes applied to select
             'data-live-search' => 'true',
             'style' => 'width:100%'
          ]
     );
@endforeach
```